# Autoincrement not working on the ID column of type serial

Tags: postgresql

I have a table whose DDL looks as follows

```
create table if not exists people
(
    id serial not null
        constraint people_pkey
            primary key,
    name varchar,
    height varchar,
    mass varchar,
    hair_color varchar,
    skin_color varchar,
    eye_color varchar,
    birth_year varchar,
    gender varchar,
    planet_id integer
        constraint people_planet_id_fkey
            references planet,
    created varchar,
    edited varchar,
    url varchar
);
```

That said when I try to insert data without mentioning the `id` I get the message that the value already exists for the `id` column(it complains that the ID Postgres Engine had chosen already exists - which is correct). I was thinking that Postgres would automatically calculate the correct value and use it, much like MS SQL Server does with the `IDENTITY` key.

Can you please let me know what I should be doing to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: with modern Postgres versions, `identity` columns are preferred over `serial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on the `id` column:

```
id serial constraint people_pkey primary key,
```

or use the following variant with `NOT NULL`:

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_name_id_seq') constraint people_pkey primary key
```

The `serial` type already is `NOT NULL` behind the scenes.

Comment: when I try to remove not_null , my IDE (data-grip) in this case complains that it cannot remove it because its a primary field.

Comment: Delete the entire row, and then add then try adding the correct version.